# How to select matches in the same table in BigQuery without Join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Please notice this is not **MySQL** I am talking about **BigQuery**

I need to perform the following operation on Google Big-Query

```
SELECT * FROM searchable.keyword AS kw1, 
(SELECT keyword From searchable.keyword 
    GROUP BY keyword ORDER BY keyword DESC) AS kw2 
WHERE kw1.keyword CONTAINS(kw2.keyword)
# or  even kw1.keyword = kw2.keyword <-- I don't need this now but it doesn't work as well
```

It's giving error that kw2 is unknown and kw1 as well

Notice: I can perform this query with JOIN then filter, but the problem is that the table has more than 450K entries, Such join will results in a huge amount 450K square, as the join condition is the parent ID, and the 450K have the same parent ID, and BigQuery doesn't allow you to add Anything in the join condition except Table1.field = Table2.field

Comment: Can you leave some sample data that explains what you are trying to do? A public BigQuery table with sample data would be great for trying out alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues... the first is that bigquery only supports equi-join -- that is, you can only join on exact equality. The second is that comma is UNION ALL not JOIN (this is unfortunate legacy behavior)
To do this, you'll need to compute the full cross join:

```
(SELECT keyword, 1 as cross FROM searchable.keyword) AS kw1 
JOIN EACH
    (SELECT keyword, 1 as cross FROM searchable.keyword GROUP BY keyword) 
ON kw1.cross = kw2.cross
WHERE kw1.keyword CONTAINS(kw2.keyword)
```

Of course, this cross join is going to explode for a reasonably large-sized table.

Comment: I did it like that already, but I'll mark the answer true as It's actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT * FROM searchable.keyword AS kw1, 
(SELECT keyword From searchable.keyword 
    GROUP BY keyword ORDER BY keyword DESC) AS kw2 
WHERE INSTR(kw1.keyword, kw2.keyword,1,1) <>0;
```

Comment: The problem is not in "CONTAINS" or "INSTR" read the error above.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I would tackle this:

1. Use the Lag and Lead functions. this way you could run on a single table, and extract following records with same values (it will work only for =, or contains in the beginning of the string.)
2. Create a full cross join by using a fictive join condition, and then put your condition in the WHERE clause. Something like this:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT *, 1 as one from table) A
   JOIN
   (SELECT *, 1 as one from table) B
   ON A.One=B.One
   WHERE INSTR(A.keyword, B.keyword,1,1) <>0
   ```

the performance won't be great, but it will work.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this will work with google big-query but you may try this syntax

```
(SELECT * FROM searchable.keyword) kw1, 
(SELECT keyword From searchable.keyword 
GROUP BY keyword ORDER BY keyword DESC) kw2 
WHERE kw1.keyword CONTAINS(kw2.keyword)
```